# Код работает в intellij но отказывается работать будучи упакованным в Jar/

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, jar

При попытке запустить jar файл через консоль я получаю такую ошибку, однако если запускать код через Intellij то ничего подобного нету.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В Гугл нашел решение через добавление плагина maven, однако в у меня оно не работает.

вот pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>untitled</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
            <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.15.3</version>
        </dependency>
 
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>org.example.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>assemble-all</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project
```

Прошу сильно не ругаться, я новичок что в java что на этом сайте

Comment: Как запускаете jar в консоли?

Comment: просто java -jar start.jar

Comment: а откуда этот start.jar берете и как его собираете?

Comment: через maven по кнопке package

Comment: он по идее должен был называтьс `untitled-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Comment: НУ вообще он так и называется, но для удобства я его переименовываю. Прошу прощения что сразу не сказал, затупил

Comment: assemly plugin далеко не всегда умеет создавать jar-with-dependencies (годится для очень простых случаев). Это очень нетривиальная задача. Используйте https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/ или если не сработает, то spring boot. В доке по spring boot описаны некоторые проблемы с shadow jar и как spring boot их обходит https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html#appendix.executable-jar.nested-jars

Comment: Прошу прощения, но не могли бы вы подсказать что мне вписывать в поле <configuration>
          <!-- put your configurations here -->
        </configuration> ?

Comment: Я попробовал воспользоваться maven-shade-plugin но результат все такой же. В intellij все работает как нужно но при запуске из под Jar выдает всю ту же ошибку

Comment: Я оставил ответ - отпишитесь как попробуете.

Comment: если ответ помог то см: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Единственный вариант, который я вижу - это смена `maven-assembly-plugin` на специализированный  `spring-boot-maven-plugin`, который заточен на то, чтобы запускать и собирать проекты на базе Spring Boot

## Причина

`maven-assembly-plugin` просто распаковывает все содержимое каждой зависимости и кладёт их в корень вашего jar-архива перезаписывая при этом одноименные конфигурационные файлы из разных пакетов spring, что в дальнейшем приводит к ошибкам

`spring-boot-maven-plugin` же деликатно раскладывает все свои зависимости по папкам и подключает каждую из них отдельно

## Что делаем?

из pom.xml удаляем

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>org.example.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>assemble-all</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

И заменяем его на

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

после чего пересобираем проект с помощью maven

```
mvn package
```

пробуем запустить

```
java -jar target/untitled-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо.